# replace relative path with a regular expression on asyncronously loaded css

Tags: javascript, css, regex, url

I'm asyncronously loading a css.

```
@font-face{
    src: url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.svg#LeHavreLight') format('svg');
}
```

I have to replace the path dynamically, for example:

```
url(' -> url('http://www.site.com/skin/light/
```

I wrote this regular expression but it seems to replace only the first value.

```
var newCss = cssText.replace(/url\(\'(.+)\'\)/g, function(a,b){
    return 'url(\''+'http://www.site.com/skin/light/' + b + '\')';
});
```

How can I replace all the url attributes?

Comment: perfect! but why do you write the answer in a comment?

Comment: couldn't remember if multi-line was disabled in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the /m modifier too. Since the string has multiple lines, it probably needs it.

```
/url\('([^)]+)'\)/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp`/url\(\'(.+?)\'\)/g` solves the problem, because of the un-greediness of the expression `.+?`, in contrast to the greedy expression `.+` that matches to the *entire* following string
(if multi-line enabled):

```
url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/le-havre-1_300_normal-webfont.svg#LeHavreLight') format('svg')
```

See the "U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)" modifier: [Pattern Modifiers @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)